# Override parent div's z-index?

Tags: html, css

I have a slideshow with this structure:

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="slide">
        <img>
        <h3>caption</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Carousel` has a background gradient style, but the gradient is running over both the image and the caption. I want it to only go over the image so the text remains bright white on top.

I'm working in Drupal and don't have the luxury of adding or changing divs. I tried using z-index and got nowhere. I tried moving the background style to `Slide` and to the image but it wouldn't display.

How can I reorder these layers using only CSS?

Thanks!

Comment: Do the divs that you are applying a z-index to have either position: relative or position: absolute on them? They need one or the other to be able to apply z-index.

Comment: Yes, I've made sure all are using relative or absolute. Good check, though!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this:

```
<div id="carousel">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/daisy_pollen_flower_220533.jpg">
        <h3>caption</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#carousel{/* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#87e0fd+0,53cbf1+40,05abe0+100;Blue+3D+%23+16 */
background: #87e0fd; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%, #53cbf1 40%, #05abe0 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #87e0fd 0%,#53cbf1 40%,#05abe0 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#87e0fd', endColorstr='#05abe0',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
height:300px;width:600px
}
img{width:20%}
```

JSFIDDLE: `https://jsfiddle.net/m46doct1/4/`

Comment: Not quite, I want the order to be: background image, gradient, text. I got that order to work by playing with the JSFiddle, but it won't work on my site. Any ideas what could be getting in the way?